# How to notify UI on volley success MVVM architecture

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-mvvm

I am using **mvvm architecture** I would like to notify view when volley post request is successful, what i could do is to instantiate ViewModel in `appRepository` class and then post values to a `liveData`, but i guess that's not a good approach as I haven't seen a similar practice. Can anyone suggest me a good approach to return my response to ui, or at least notify that post request has been successful.

**From fragment/View I trigger this method**

```
// save data to api

checkInViewModel.updateEventPersonEntity(eventPersonsEntity);
```

**ViewModel forwards it to apprespository**

```
public void updateEventPersonEntity(EventPersonsEntity eventPersonsEntity) {
    mRepository.updateEventPersonEntity(eventPersonsEntity);
}
```

AppRepository.Java class

```
    public void updateEventPersonEntity(EventPersonsEntity eventPersonsEntity) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
           // mDb.eventPersonsDao().update(eventPersonsEntity);

            if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                post_updateEventPersonEntity(eventPersonsEntity);
            }
        });
    }

private void post_updateEventPersonEntity(EventPersonsEntity eventPersonsEntity) {

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("EventPersonId", eventPersonsEntity.getEventPersonId());
        params.put("EventId", eventPersonsEntity.getEventId());
        params.put("PersonId", eventPersonsEntity.getPersonId());
        params.put("CashStart", parseDoubleToGerman(eventPersonsEntity.getCashStart()));
        params.put("CashEnd", parseDoubleToGerman(eventPersonsEntity.getCashEnd()));
        params.put("StartingTime", String.valueOf(eventPersonsEntity.getStartingTime()));
        params.put("EndingTime", String.valueOf(eventPersonsEntity.getEndingTime()));
        params.put("isChekcedIn", eventPersonsEntity.getIsCheckedIn());
        params.put("isChekcedOut", eventPersonsEntity.getIsCheckedOut());

        JSONObject objRegData = new JSONObject(params);

        String eventPersonApi = APP_URL.EVENT_PERSONS_API + eventPersonsEntity.getEventPersonId();
        RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(context).objectRequest(eventPersonApi, Request.Method.PUT, this::onSuccess_updateEventPersonEntity, this::onError, objRegData);

    }

    private void onError(VolleyError error) {

        Log.d(APP_REPOSITORY_TAG, "requestError: " + error);
    }

    private void onSuccess_updateEventPersonEntity(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        // notify ui

    }
```

Comment: You should add a callback to your repository method for your view model to provide. You should never hold reference to your view model in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this same as you did for your success response logic in repository. Simply create new callback interface:

```
interface OnEventUpdatedListener{
    void eventUpdated();
}
```

Then, update your method to look like this, passing the listener to the actual method that does the work:

```
    public void updateEventPersonEntity(EventPersonsEntity eventPersonsEntity, OnEventUpdatedListener listener) {
    mRepository.updateEventPersonEntity(eventPersonsEntity, listener);
}
```

Pass this inside your:

```
            if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            post_updateEventPersonEntity(eventPersonsEntity, listener);
        }
```

After that, in your `onSuccess()` method simply call:

```
    private void onSuccess_updateEventPersonEntity(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    listener.eventUpdated();

}
```

Finally, you will have the info when the update happens, in the calling site, if you call your repository like this:

```
        updateEventPersonEntity(null, new OnEventUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void EventUpdated() {
            // Do your logic here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Samir, much appreciated. Using your suggested method.